# How to store YouTube iframe watched time in database

Tags: reactjs, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I want to track the progress of the watchtime of a video and store it in my database. I don't know what's an efficient way to do this, because I don't think that its good to update a table each second.

**This is my iframe, I am using React**

```
<iframe
    src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${curvideo}`}
    frameborder="0"
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
    classname="w-full h-full absolute top-0 left-0 rounded-st"
></iframe>
```

Thank's for helping out!

Comment: First, how you define `watched time` in this scenario?